# Laravel Lumen Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\responce()

Tags: php, laravel, api, lumen

When I try to call API then I got this error.
Here is My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Video;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class VideoController extends Controller
{
   public function index(){
    //return 'index function of video controller';
    $Video  =  DB::table('videos')->get();
    return responce()->json($Video);

  }
}
?>
```

here is my web.php

```
$app->get('/', 'VideoController@index');
```

Comment: It's response, not responce `return response()->json($Video);`

Comment: its working fine thanx @b0ne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return `$Video` or any other variable or array, not a function `response()`

EDIT

try to just `return json_encode($Video);`

Comment: ohh sorry It was a mistake now I correct it and getting same error. Please have a look